# How to create scrollable month and add a list of events for each month?

Tags: android, calendarview

I want to have something like a `CalendarView` where you can scroll and swipe left and right to see different months I don't need the days of the month displayed. I would just like to have a list of events for each month. Something like the diagram below.

How can I do this? I came across the `CalendarView` API, and I am wondering is it possible to hide the dates to achieve the effect I want?
[image: ;]

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use `CalendarView` for this: that class is tightly coupled with `CalendarViewDelegate` which is platform native and cannot be customized easily.

A better approach might be to create a [ViewPager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) that is populated with the data you want on each swipe. Steps:

1. Create a layout that is a template for what you want for each month, e.g. a title bar with a `TextView` for month name and buttons for left and right.
2. Create a `Fragment` that returns the above layout in the `onCreateView` method.
3. Add a `ViewPager` to allow scrolling/swiping left right through the views. You will have to set the content (month name, events) using an adapter. See the [linked tutorial from Google](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html).

Comment: Thanks for the pointers! will definitely go and examine ViewPager more